# What are the technical reasons to avoid injecting the service container instead of individual services?

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection

Normally when I need to inject one or more services into another service, I explicitly inject each one. However, I have a situation where injecting the service container itself will really make things easier. I know this is not a recommended practice, but I'm curious what the technical reasons are for discouraging this. Is it something legitimate like it's too resource intensive, or a more personal feeling that it's too messy?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you inject the container, you're not making dependencies clear.  In fact, you're obscuring them more than before.  If you have a class like this...

```
class DocumentCreator(IFileNamer fileNamer, IRepository repository)
{ ... }
```

...you can see what the dependencies are.  You can also easily mock those dependencies for unit testing, to ensure that you isolate the DocumentCreator and can know that any test failures are a result of its code rather than code in one of its dependencies.

If, on the other hand, you do this...

```
class DocumentCreator(IDependencyContainer container)
{ ... }
```

...you've obscured the dependencies.  You can't know, without examining the internals of the class, that it requires an IFileNamer and an IRepository.

Nor can you easily know what mocks you need to put in the container in order to test DocumentCreator.  Mocking the IDependencyContainer won't help you at all; your class will still fail in testing because the container won't contain an IFileNamer and an IRepository, unless you examine the internals of the class to see that they're required.

Answer (score 7):

What you describe is a ServiceLocator. This is considered an anti-pattern in modern application design. [This article](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorIsAnAntiPattern.aspx) describes why.

Comment: False. People really need to stop linking to that dude's blog. Here's insight from a more skilled master of patterns. 
http://www.martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html

Comment: @Colin You ever read Mark Seemann's reasoning for declaring ServiceLocator an anti-pattern? You only gain a few of the advantages of full dependency injection but miss quite a few of the benefits (i.e. the instant visibility of dependencies). I addition SL violates various rules of software design like encapsulation http://blog.ploeh.dk/2015/10/26/service-locator-violates-encapsulation/ or SOLID http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/05/15/service-locator-violates-solid/

Comment: Yes, and it's nonsense. In fact, the opposite of his argument is true. For example, he says it "spoils encapsulation", but the whole point of encapsulation is to hide the internal details of the class that the caller shouldn't be concerned with (like validation, which he externalizes in his example). DI has clear applications and benefits but it's not a "golden hammer"; THAT's an anti-pattern. Think if you had to pass in TraceListeners every time you called Trace.WriteLine() or Debug.WriteLine()! I wish people would stop treating Mr. Seeman like an expert; he's a just an opinionated blogger.

Comment: @Colin Were you ever in a situation where a class offered you a parameterless constructor and then refused to work because you had to initialize half a dozen "internal details" in some seemingly unrelated code? No? Lucky you. If I got paid extra for every hour I have to waste to locate and deal with such "internal details" I could spend half the year on vacation. The Trace class has a static collection of listeners. Thats an obvious dependency not an "internal detail" btw.

Comment: You're missing the point. When you call trace, do you pass the listeners in the constructor every time? Does a DI container property-inject the listeners? Typically not and, in fact, the listeners are often initialized via... a text-based configuration file (*gasp*)! By contrast, a purist-DI approach might instead pass a composite logger class in via a constructor and, in most cases, that would be a more cumbersome, less flexible approach. Again, I'm not saying DI is never the right choice, I'm just saying that, at times, alternatives like a Sevice Locator or Provider might be appropriate.

Comment: @Colin, you're right, it's important to hide the internal details of a class.  The trouble is, by injecting the service container, you're hiding _external_ details of the class.  The dependencies of a class are part of the public API as much as the methods and properties are.  If you need to supply X and Y in order for a class to function, how will you know that if the class doesn't explicitly require X and Y (e.g. through the constructor)?  "When the class blows up at runtime" is not a good answer to this question.

Comment: @Kryalessa - Dependencies of a class needn’t be part of a public API; sometimes it’s best to hide away that detail. Have you ever had to pass dependency information into a REST-ful API? You shouldn’t have to care! Furthermore, most DI frameworks blow up at runtime (albeit at the time of startup configuration vs. within a method call). All of this said, I regularly use DI, I just advise against judging it to be “the only way” with religiosity. Sometimes it’s best, sometimes it isn’t.

Answer (score 4):

I think the main problem with this approach is that you don't see the dependencies clearly anymore. Another problem might be that it is more difficult to test.

Comment: I definitely agree with the first part, and that's why except for rare situations I still continue to inject specific services. But I'm not sure how testing it would be more difficult?

Comment: It would imply to create the container object, and inject mocked (or not mocked) services into it, instead of injecting them directly, which makes one more step.

Comment: Hmm, that is definitely a big disadvantage.